# Xcode unit test on memory leaks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

A ViewController counts its instances:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    static var instances: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ViewController.instances = ViewController.instances + 1
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    deinit {
        ViewController.instances = ViewController.instances - 1
    }
}
```

Try it in a default iOS Single View App where it will be the root view controller of the app's UIWindow.

A unit test tries to check the result by putting a dummy view controller on that same UIWindow:

```
func testExample() {
    guard let w = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window else { return }
    w?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    XCTAssert(ViewController.instances == 0)
}
```

But the test fails, the ViewController has not been released.

I am guessing the autoreleasepool of the host application is drained only after the unit test has run. Is there a way to drain it before testing the ViewController.instances? Any other way to write a test like this?

Comment: Note that the test validates a very small set of controller's methods. You'll likely need to call all methods that might cause leaks, which can prove to be unfeasible for unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your snippet the `window` retains the `ViewController`.

The way I solve this is to override `tearDown()` and make sure `window.rootViewController` (and anything else I created in setUp() is set no nil:

```
var window: UIWindow!

override func tearDown() {        
    window.rootViewController = nil
    window = nil
    super.tearDown()
}
```

EDITED. To verify that the viewcontroller deinit method is called you can do:

```
func testExample() {
    autoreleasepool {
        self.window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    }
        expect(Myvc.retaincount).toEventually(equal(0))
    }
```

This is using Nimble testing framework to wait for the value to be 0. You should be able to write that in plain XCTest using an asynchronous test.

Comment: I tried that, but it does not help. Maybe you're doing something different from me? (gist: https://gist.github.com/ristkof/de947d7f045e8a4af2086a065c943ed3 )

Comment: If you want to test `deinit` you will probably need to wrap your test into `autoreleasepool` block and write the assert to test instances being zero as asynchronous test.

Comment: ok that seems to work... but I don't understand it. The tearDown part is unnecessary + the ViewController was not in the autoreleasepool, how did that autoreleasepool clean up ViewController? Also: why is there a need to wait? The autoreleasepool should be cleaned up immediately after the closing bracket, right? gist of working code: https://gist.github.com/ristkof/3e1cfba6011491259d59839e0722e25b

Comment: I think this is down to the fact how XCTest works and internally derives test case blocks out of test classes.

Comment: I may accept this as an answer if nothing more satisfying comes up in the next couple of days, but for now let me say this: this fixes this sample-case, but it does not work for my complicated case in my code base of which this sample was a simplification. Not really understanding what is going on is not helping me much to write a working unit test, so for now I'm a bit stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different and more universal way to write tests that check for memory leaks in view controllers. It can help detect leaks that could be made in any life cycle method of a view controller (*viewWillAppear*, *viewDidAppear* etc.).

Add following extension in your tests:

```
extension XCTestCase {
    func checkViewControllerDeallocation(with viewControllerInitBlock: () -> UIViewController) {
        let rootVC = UIViewController()
        let window = UIWindow()
        window.rootViewController = rootVC
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        weak var weakVC: UIViewController?
        let releaseExpectation = XCTestExpectation()
        autoreleasepool {
            let vc = viewControllerInitBlock()
            rootVC.present(vc, animated: false, completion: {
                weakVC = rootVC.presentedViewController
                XCTAssert(weakVC != nil)
                rootVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
                    releaseExpectation.fulfill()
                })
            })
        }
        wait(for: [releaseExpectation], timeout: 10)
        let nilWeakExpectation = XCTestExpectation()
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true, block: { [weak weakVC] _ in
            if weakVC == nil {
                nilWeakExpectation.fulfill()
            }
        })
        wait(for: [nilWeakExpectation], timeout: 10)
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Then write tests like this:

```
func testMyViewControllerDeallocation() {
    checkViewControllerDeallocation(with: {
        let vc = MyViewController() // or init from storyboard
        // optionally you can also configure vc if needed
        return vc
    })
}
```